# arc enabled cocos2d - old scene lives after replaceScene

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, automatic-ref-counting, scene

I'm trying to implement a game with cocos2d. I enabled arc according to the instructions on this tutorial.
http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/04/enabling-arc-cocos2d-project-howto-stepbystep-tutorialguide/

I realized a weird behavior after replacing game scene with main menu scene and I can't figure out the problem. After replacement, the new scene appears and works as I expected, but the game scene (old scene) still reacts touches. I thought that when I replace the scene, old scene should be removed completely, but it continue to live under the new scene.

Some of the relevant code is as follows:

Singleton:

```
+(void) go: (CCLayer *) layer{
    CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
    CCScene *newScene = [Singelton wrap:layer];
    if ([director runningScene]) {
        [director replaceScene: [CCTransitionFlipX transitionWithDuration:0.5 scene:newScene]];
    } else {
        [director pushScene:newScene];
    }
}

+(CCScene *) wrap: (CCLayer *) layer{
    CCScene *newScene = [CCScene node];
    [newScene addChild: layer];
    return newScene;
}

+(void) mainMenu
{
    CCLayer *layer = [MainMenu node];
    [Singleton go:layer];
}
```

When I need to go to main menu scene I call singleton class as follows

```
[Singleton mainMenu]
```

How can I kill the game scene after menu scene appears?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

What does Singleton do? I suspect that it might be the cause, holding on to references of the Scene/Layer or any other nodes while/after replacing a scene.

Comment: Actually there is a bad naming for this class - sorry for misleading. This is not a singleton class, just a scene manager like in the following tutorial. So there is no references of the scenes after loading.

http://www.iphonegametutorials.com/2010/09/07/cocos2d-menu-tutorial/